# Ubuntu started in console only mode, how can I go back to GUI?

Tags: console

I restarted ubuntu and now it's console only, it asks for my login (which I know). How can I go back to GUI?

This is on VMWare by the way

Comment: Is this a GUIless server install?

Comment: No, it was working until now. I hadn't used this for some months, now I logged in and restarted a couple of times and this last time I just got sent into this screen.

Comment: ALT+CTRL+F7 doesn't work, although I can switch between ALT+CTRL+F1-F6.

Answer (score 0):

On the Console type

```
sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

and then reboot your system.
This should work in most cases but if it doesn't try if you are using gdm

```
sudo systemctl enable gdm
```

--

```
sudo ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service' '/etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service'
```

reboot.

Comment: So I tried the first thing you suggested and rebooting didn't fix it, it went back to the console thing. The second part didn't work either, gave out an error, let me copy it here: Failed to enable unit. Unit file gdm.service does not exist

Comment: sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target

Comment: try this if doesn't work can you post the grub text ?

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm          or remove and install back

Comment: 'lightdm' is not installed. What's the grub text?

Comment: sudo apt install lightdm

Comment: after that type    sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm   and try switching between gdm or ldm

Comment: I think it just died, I restarted again to try what you said and now it's just blinking some white text about "Assuming drive cache" bla bla bla

Comment: I think GUI is not installed, try reinstalling.

Comment: or try installing gnome package but i recommend reinstalling in such cases